# Swift - Access elements of the modal popup within UITableViewController in order to pass the data from Firebase database to modal popup elements

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I'm new to iOS development and need your help.

I'm using UITableView to build a table of tasks. Tasks data is transmitted from Firebase database. When I click the button on task cell, modal popup window (within the same ViewController via animate method) is opened.

I want to access elements of modal popup in order to pass the data of the specific task from database to its modal window.

I have TaskViewCell file with all cell elements outlets, such as previewTitleLabel, previewMotivLabel etc.

TasksListScreen file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class TasksListScreen: UIViewController {
    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    var tasksArray = [Task]() // array of tasks using Task struct

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerPopupConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundButton: UIButton!

    // show popup  
    @IBAction func yesButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        centerPopupConstraint.constant = 0 // popup appear

        // add slide animation for popup
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.backgroundButton.alpha = 0.5
        })
    }

    // done button on popup is clicked
    @IBAction func closePopup(_ sender: Any) {
        centerPopupConstraint.constant = -450 // popup disappear

        // add slide animation for popup
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.backgroundButton.alpha = 0
        })
    }
 }

extension TasksListScreen: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return tasksArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell") as! TaskViewCell
   let task = tasksArray[indexPath.row]

   cell.previewTitleLabel.text = task.title  
   cell.previewMotivLabel.text = task.tip  
   cell.previewHashtagsLabel.text = task.hashtags  

   // Here I want to access task's modal window to pass data to its elements:
   // the same task title and task description form database

}}
```

Please help!!

[TasksListScreen storyboard with modal popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkaY6.png)

[Files hierarchy view and TasksListScreen storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu6mK.png)

[App appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGFqo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, I solved this issue.

In order to pass data of the selected row to new VC or modal window, you need to give an identifier to your segue between table view VC and new VC, and use two functions:

```
// change VC
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
} 

// pass the data to new VC
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? HeroViewController {
            destination.hero = heroes[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
 }
```